# How can I get the specific database error message from exception DatabaseError?

Tags: python, django

I'm able to catch `DatabaseError`, but outputting it in the console displays all parameters, which I don't care for.

How can I get specific pieces of data, such as the query executed, error text, error name, etc...

I attempted to debug the `DatabaseError` object using `dir()` as well as looking at the source code, but nothing jumps out at me. The documentation makes mention of the `__cause__` attribute, but again, this is one big string containing the query executed, params, error text, etc. It's quite a big mess.

Comment: Ref this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/exceptions/#database-exceptions it looks like you can use error.__cause__ to get the underlying exception. According to the docs, that's the underlying exception, not a string - are you sure that it's really a string and you're not just looking at the string representation?

Comment: Right you were! See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the error message by doing the following -

```
e.__cause__.__context__.excepinfo[2]
```

Seems quite cumbersome, so I'll probably wrap the context in a class so I can create attributes.